# GCD of two numbers in python

Tags: python

I have been trying to find the GCD of nos in python, How do i implement while not in python??

```
no=raw_input("Enter a number")
a=float(no)
nos=raw_input("Enter a number")
b=float(nos)
while(b!==0)

 t=a%b
 a=b
 b=t
 print a
```

Is there a way to use a for loop here??

Comment: Unless you want to implement your own, there is a built in which does this for you: https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html

Comment: How can a FOR loop be used here? just wondering..that is all!

Comment: lol @J.F.Sebastian :P not sure what you said but based on the blue text its probably a good suggestion

Comment: @karthikr: Python 3.5 introduces [`math.gcd()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/math.html#math.gcd) function that is slightly different from [`fractions.gcd()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/fractions.html#fractions.gcd) (different behavior for negative integers, different input type requirements). Here's a [couple of related](http://bugs.python.org/issue22477) [Python issues](http://bugs.python.org/issue22486).

Comment: @JoranBeasley: sorry, wrong language. I've somehow thought that I'm on [ru.SO](http://ru.stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 1):

```
while b != 0:
     t = a % b
     a = b
     b = t
     print a
```

Comment: Note that `a, b = b, a % b` will also work, and is somewhat neater

Comment: Yep it does! Thank You all!

Comment: Also, `while b` is enough.

Comment: man this problem is so well suited for recursion I cant help but alway jump instantly to the recursive solution

Comment: Isn't this answer already in the question? (just indented) :P